# What happens if you divide by Zero on a computer?

Tags: math, programming-languages, hardware, arithmetic-expressions, divide-by-zero

What happens if you divide by Zero on a Computer?

In any given programming languange (I worked with, at least) this raises an error. 
But why? Is it built in the language, that this is prohibited? Or will it compile, and the hardware will figure out that an error must be returned?

I guess handling this by the language can only be done, if it is hard code, e.g. there is a line like `double z = 5.0/0.0;` If it is a function call, and the devisor is given from outside, the language could not even know that this is a division by zero (at least a compile time).

```
double divideByZero(double divisor){
    return 5.0/divisor;
}
```

where divisor is called with `0.0`.

**Update:**
According to the comments/answers it makes a difference whether you divide by `int 0` or `double 0.0`.
I was not aware of that. This is interesting in itself and I'm interested in both cases.

Also one answer is, that the CPU throws an error. Now, how is this done? Also in software (doesn't make sense on a CPU), or are there some circuits which recognize this? I guess this happens on the Arithmetic Logic Unit (ALU).

Comment: In interpreted languages, or other languages which have a substantial runtime, "the language" can very well know what the divisor is. In compiled languages such a check could be compiled into the binary. The only time "the language" wouldn't know is if it's compiled straight to machine code without such a check.

Answer (score 4):

When an integer is divided by 0 in the CPU, this causes an interrupt.¹ A programming language implementation can then handle that interrupt by throwing an exception or employing whichever other error-handling mechanisms the language has.

When a floating point number is divided by 0, the result is infinity, NaN or negative infinity (which are special floating point values). That's mandated by the IEEE floating point standard, which any modern CPU will adhere to. Programming languages generally do as well. If a programming language wanted to handle it as an error instead, it could just check for NaN or infinite results after every floating point operation and cause an error in that case. But, as I said, that's generally not done.

---

¹ On x86 at least. But I imagine it's the same on most other architectures as well.

Comment: The code in the question shows a floating point number, not an integer.

Comment: @svick I added the situation for floating point numbers to my answer, but I assume the OP just used them by mistake (as the OP's claim that division by 0 raises an error in most languages just isn't true for floating point numbers).

Comment: is dividing floating point number by 0 just as fast as normal division? (without causing interrupt?)